# Enabling bookmarking on a UIWebView (to make shortcuts on springboard)

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiwebview, bookmarks

I wan't to add shortcuts on my springboard form my application.

The way i'm following is loading a UIWebView and then trying to add a bookmark. But I can't figure out how to add the "+" button to bookmark the content of my WebView...

Is there a way to do so ? Or is there another way to add shortcuts on the springboard programmatically ?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible within the SDK. Adding bookmark icons to the home screen is a feature of the Safari app, and definitely not exposed through `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    //toolbar
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *bookmarkBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(bookmark)];
    // add btns to the bar
[toolBar setItems:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bookmarkBtn,backBtn,etc..., nil]];

// adds the toobar to the view
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

and the action implementation:

```
-(void)bookmarksBtn
{ [yourView yourAction]; }
```